# error while creating iPhone distribution certificate?

Tags: iphone, app-store, distribution

i have successfuly created provisioning certificates and tested the app on my device, but while uploading to appstore i got some error related with distribution profile, the error says  " valid signing identity not found ".

[image]while adding distribution certificate i got this error on organizer? anyone knows the solution? i tried recreating the certificate but the error remains?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you made the certificate signing request, you made a key, that key is deleted due to whcih you are getting this.

to overcome, make a new key, new certificate and then new profile again, bt make sure to delete all profiles matching to that first from your organizer

Comment: thankyou, but that error was done, please help with this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482019/distribution-profile-not-displaying-while-posting-app-on-appstore

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't have the certificate file installed on this mac system for the mobile provision. Either you are on a different mac machine or don't have distribution certificate. If you are on a different mac machine then you should export the certificate in .p12 format from keychain access from your previous mac (where you installed the certificate) or if you don't have a distribution certificate then create a distribution certificate.

Post in comments if you face any issue.