# distribution profile not displaying while posting app on appstore?

Tags: iphone, app-store, distribution

i have successfully created provisioning and distribution certificates and ready to upload my app. but, while posting i can't access to select the distribution profile? [image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you changed your distribution profile both in target as well as in project settings, and make all the profiles to the distribution.

Comment: Did you drag the provisioning profile to xcode that you created

Comment: @TheSaad yes i changed that in the project settings and for sorry i can't understand changing your distribution profile both in target, u mean bundle settings?

Comment: @iosDev yes i double clicked the profiles and i think it automatically added to my project

Comment: nope, http://yannickloriot.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/Link-CoreData-Framework-To-The-Project.png

Comment: see image here. it has two parts, both project and target has to be configured with profiles.

Comment: and next sett all the parameters to the new file carefully as this image shows, not only above or below  ones but all lines

Comment: http://timroadley.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/SetCodeSign.png

Comment: and do you generated the distribution profile for appstore? or it was adhoc there when u made the profile

Comment: @NeerajNeeru: Make sure you have selected "Release" to be run under "Archive" under Manage Schemes.

Comment: @TheSaad yes i created the distribution profile for appstore and double click to add this into my project

Comment: @NeerajNeeru: Make sure you have selected "Release" to be run under "Archive" under Manage Schemes before you build for archiving and archive the app.

Comment: that was i m asking you make sure you have set all the lines with profile

Comment: @ParthBhatt i done that already , but the error remains,

Comment: @NeerajNeeru: Go to your account and check if your profile is valid and re-download it. Also you need to check if the App ID you created is fine.

Comment: @NeerajNeeru I think in youe keychain there are two same distribution profile. So check it and delete both and install again.

Comment: @NeerajNeeru: I have edited my answer and added one link. Please check it.

Comment: @JohnWhite thankyou, i have deleted the copy. now it works fine

Comment: @TheSaad thankyou for your help. now problem solved . i have uploaded my app through application loader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@NeerajNeeru:

Firstly, Make sure that you download a new copy of distribution provisioning profile for App Store from the account you want to submit the application with and install the same profile by double clicking it. Once you do that select it under your `Project Settings` and `Target Settings` under the `Release` section.

Secondly, Make sure you have selected `Release` to be run under `Archive` under `Manage Schemes` before you build for archiving and archive the app.

Once you select `Release` under `Archive` in `Manage Schemes`, make sure you do `Product -> Clean` your application and then do `Product -> Build For Archiving` and then `Product -> Archive`.

**EDIT:**

Refer to this: [Xcode 4.3: Codesign operation failed (Check that the identity you selected is valid)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386925/xcode-4-3-codesign-operation-failed-check-that-the-identity-you-selected-is-va)

Let me know if you need more help

Hope this helps.

Comment: thankyou, for your feed back. i found the problem .. its because of not cleaning and  Build For Archiving the project and also in keychain there are two same distribution profile, so i deleted one and did the procedure one by one. now i uploaded my app through application loader.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have not opened the downloaded profile, download the profile from developer.apple.com and doble click it. it will be able to select now, and re assign profile in your project and target files even they have already selected.